# Why is the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $ x^2 - 8x + 15 \leq 0 $ representable as a polyhedron?

Tags: polynomials, polyhedra, real-algebraic-geometry

I was attempting this tutorial question:

> a) For each of the following sets, decide whether it is representable as a polyhedron.
>
> (ii) The set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$x^2 − 8x + 15 \leq 0$$

The corresponding answer was :

> (ii) The second set can be expressed as $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the two linear constraints $x \geq 3$, $x \leq 5$. Hence it is representable as a polyhedron.

This result puzzled me. My current understanding is the set satisfying $ x^2 - 8x + 15 \leq 0 $, $x$ can be expressed as the set in $ \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $ x \geq 3 $ and $  x \le 5 $. However, this corresponds to the curved region of the quadratic region which has an infinite number of points. To my understanding, in a polyhedron, there are only a finite number of vertices.

Just wondering if anyone could help me clear my misconceptions.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is too vague right now. Please edit it to include the exact wording of the tutorial question and the answer given and your answer. Then perhaps we can help clear up misconceptions.

Comment: Misconception: "polyhedra". It's a plural, that's why the original had "polyhedron". In $\mathbb{R}^1$, a polyhedron has a finite number (2) of vertices, and is an interval.

Comment: My apologies, that was my mistake, the question asked for a polyhedron . Thank you for helping me clear up that misconception though!

Comment: Why are you puzzled? The set is an interval. Representing intervals using a conjunction of strict inequalities is easy.

Comment: In what sense is $3 \leq x \leq 5$ curved? It' an interval on $\mathbb{R}$. I think you are thinking of the set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ below or over the quadratic function.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Thanks so much @JohanLöfberg  !